# Javascript Fetch API can't control the coming response

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am trying to fetch some information from the given URL. I assigned the URL to a const named URL. I used the fetch api to take the info from the source as JSON format. I can't control the coming information.Here is my code;

```
const fetch = require("cross-fetch");
const URL = "https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/books"


// Important: Don't change the function name
const getBooks = async () => {
  // Your code goes here
  
  
  const response = await fetch(`${URL}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
  const books = await response.json();
  return books;
}

getBooks().then(books => console.log(books))
```

[This is the response from the code that I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6JM9.png) 
I only need the 
{
name: "...",
numberOfPages: "....",
released: "......",
},
{
name: "...",
numberOfPages: "....",
released: "......",
},
....

Comment: What is the problem having the other properties in the data received? You really haven't identified in clear and specific terms what your actual problem is here

Comment: You're mixing `await` and `.then()` syntax. This led to you calling both `.json()` and `console.log` twice. There should only be one of each in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the values that you need from the api response.
Here is the how you can do it:

```
const url = "https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/books";

const callApi = async () => {
const resp = await fetch(url);
const finalRes = await resp.json();
return finalRes.map((res) => {
    return {
    name: res.name,
    numberOfPages: res.numberOfPages,
    released: res.released,
    };
});
};

(async () => console.log(await callApi()))();
```

***Result set from browser console:***

[image]
Also, while waiting for promise to get fulfilled, you can do .then() or use await.
They both solve the same purpose.

Comment: No destructuring in your example code?

Comment: Ya, I am directly returning the required details in map function.but yes I’ll change the answer. 
Thanks for pointing it out.